# Get to know error and error codes of Mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I would like to back up our mysql database. We have huge records in the database. What are the errors can occur and possible while running mysqldump.? Mysql official site did not mention the specific error and error codes for mysqldump, They just commonly put the error and error codes. I am expecting some mysql expert can help me out. I would like to take some action in case any error happen for that I want know possible error and errocodes. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I can say that once in a whilte with BLOBS (binary large objects) and obnoxiously long insert sections, (read lots of inserts on the same table), have given way to errors.  I, whether good or bad, check the "ignore errors" box when importing again later.

And how huge are we talking?

Comment: Thank You. Yes, We have large amount of BLOBS data in our database, May be 100GB of data. I do not know, Whether this is huge amount or not. Some basic error we can avoid by setting some flag variable in mysql parameter, I have read in the documentation. But I am talking about server slowdown , huge data(allocation of buffer size) as well as timeout exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you expect to happen from a simple mysqldump? There are no errors I'm aware of and none I ever heard about.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Thank You, I heard that, Large records back up would take some couple of hours. While backup, mysql server may be slow down and mysql automatically recover itself. Isn't it?. At this time what about mysqldump status? whether mysqldump is automatically recover itself or not?